# dd Copy partition image file into disk image file

Tags: dd, fdisk

I am creating a disk image and copy a mbr on it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=2M count=256 > ./hd.img
dd if=mbr.bin of=hd.img conv=notrunc
sfdisk --force ./hd.img < partitions.sfdisk
```

where `partitions.sfdisk` looks like this:

```
2048,,0x83,*
```

`fdisk -lu hd.img` now lists this:

```
./hd.img1  *     2048 1048575  1046528  511M 83 Linux
```

with sectors of `512` bytes.

Now I want to format `hd.img1` with `ext4` without creating a loop device. So I created a second image `hd.img1` with the size of `512MB - (2048 x 512)` bytes. I executed

```
mkfs.ext4 hd.img1
```

and now I want to copy `hd.img1` into `hd.img` on the position of the created partition `hd1.img`.

Is that even possible? Do I have to `dd` `hd.img1` with an offset (skip) of `2048 x 512`?

```
dd if=hd.img1 of=hd.img skip=2048 bs=512
```

When I do that it seems that I've overwritten my partition table created with `sfdisk` so I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Instead of `dd if=/dev/zero ...` you can use `truncate` or `fallocate`. Check their manuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip` skips inside the input. **To move your starting position in the *output* file use `seek`**.

From [`man dd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd):

> `seek=BLOCKS`
>
> skip `BLOCKS` `obs`-sized blocks at start of output
>
> `skip=BLOCKS`
>
> skip `BLOCKS` `ibs`-sized blocks at start of input